# Testing foreach loop with jmockit

Tags: java, foreach, jmockit

I'm trying to write a unit test for a logic in a foreach loop, but it failed due to "Missing invocations" exception.

When debugging it I see that the `s3EventNotification.getRecords().size()` is 0.
What explain the missing invocation error, but I can't figure out how to make it enter the loop.
I also tried to add to the Expectations block

```
s3EventNotificationRecords.size();
                result = 1;
```

in order to have `s3EventNotification.getRecords().size()` = 1, but it still doesn't enter the loop.

below is the method I'm trying to test:

```
public void receiveMessages(String msg) throws IOException {
        logger.info("Message received to queue. Message = " +msg );
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            S3EventNotification s3EventNotification = mapper.readValue(msg, S3EventNotification.class);

            s3EventNotification.getRecords().forEach(record -> {
                S3EventNotification.S3Entity s3Entity = record.getS3();

                S3Object s3Object = s3Service.getS3Object(s3Entity.getBucket().getName(), s3Entity.getObject().getKey());
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error handling message",e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

and the test I wrote:

```
public class DemoAppTest {

    @Tested
    private DemoApp demoApp;

    @Injectable
    private S3Service s3Service;

    @Mocked
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Mocked
    private S3EventNotification s3EventNotification;

    @Mocked
    private S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord s3EventNotificationRecord;

    @Mocked
    private S3EventNotification.S3Entity s3Entity;

    @Mocked
    private S3Object s3Object;

    @Mocked
    private List<S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord> s3EventNotificationRecords;

    private String msg ="msg";

    @Test
    public void receiveMessagesTest() throws IOException {
        new Expectations(){
            {
                new ObjectMapper();
                result = mapper;

                mapper.readValue(msg, s3EventNotification.getClass());
                result = s3EventNotification;

                s3EventNotification.getRecords();
                result = s3EventNotificationRecords;

                s3EventNotificationRecord.getS3();
                result = s3Entity;

                s3Service.getS3Object(s3Entity.getBucket().getName(), s3Entity.getObject().getKey());
                result = s3Object;
            }
        };

        demoApp.receiveMessages(msg);
    }
}
```

The error I got is:

```
Missing 1 invocation to:
com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification$S3EventNotificationRecord#getS3()
   on mock instance: com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification$S3EventNotificationRecord@6c61a903
```

I'll very appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: Try mocking only what's reasonable to mock, ie, the `S3Service`.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking the List is disallowed in newer versions of JMockit, and is what's causing you grief here.

Change s3EventNotificationRecords to be an actual ArrayList (not a mocked one).  Then, populate that list with mocked entities.

```
s3EventNotificationRecords = new ArrayList<>();
s3EventNotificationRecords.add(s3EventNotificationRecord);
```

Now when the test runs, JMockit will mock the call to getRecords() causing the test to use your (real, but test-provided) array list populated as above.  The code will then run the forEach and pull out the mocked s3EventNotificationRecord instance.  The code will then call getS3() on the mocked instance, and test should proceed using s3Entity.